# Access Token Infinite Renewal

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am coding a social management tool. I need infinite access token for Facebook.

First please tell me if I understand this correctly;
Access Token the reason we get is for to be able to have users account permissions to application, and this Access Token has 60 days to expire. but even after that expired still user accounts permissions on application only we don't have permission to reach it?

Can I renew access token after expired? I tried something like this;

```
 void GetToken()
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

                String fb_exchange_token = null;

                fb_exchange_token = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["token"].ToString();
                String newToken = fb_exchange_token;
                var fb = new FacebookClient();
                try
                {
                    dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                    {
                        client_id = client_id,
                        client_secret = client_secret,
                        grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
                        fb_exchange_token = fb_exchange_token
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Message.Contains("expired"))
                    {
                        dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                        {
                            client_id = client_id,
                            client_secret = client_secret,
                            grant_type = "client_credentials",
                            fb_exchange_token = fb_exchange_token
                        });

                        newToken = (string)result.access_token;
                        if (newToken != fb_exchange_token)
                            SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionString, "SocialTokenUpdate", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SocialId"].ToString(), newToken);
                    }

                    DataProvider.ExceptionLogAdd("xx.aspx", "GetToken", ex.Message);
                }



                Session["Token"] = newToken;
                Session["FBPageId"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SocailFBId"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DataProvider.ExceptionLogAdd("xx.aspx", "GetToken", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate new accessToken automatically means Let the application open the first screen where user gives access to Application. Then it will generate new accessToken. If accessToken is Expired get it in OAuthException and redirect to front screen.